# Storing 3D Array on Heap as Structure Member

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct, heap-memory, new-operator

I recently started working with C++ for numerical computations where I want to use a `Struct Operators` to store 3D Fields over the course of the simulation.
I create the 3D arrays on the heap with

```
const unsigned int RES = 256;
auto arr3D = new double [RES][RES][RES];
```

because from what I've tested this approach is faster than using either Boost_multiarr, Eigen Tensor or nested Vectors.
So far this worked fine with my minimalistic Test.cpp but when I try to implement these same 3D Arrays as Members of my `Struct Operators`, I cannot use the `auto` command anymore:

```
const unsigned int RES = 256;

struct Operators {
public:
    std::complex<double>*** wfc;         // edited, see 'spitconsumers' comment

    Operators(Settings &set) {        // just another structure used by Operators
        wfc = new std::complex<double> [RES][RES][RES];

        // ...Initializing wfc using Settings

};
```

In this case I found no way of declaring `wfc`, such that I do not get errors of the type

> error: cannot convert 'std::complex (*)[256][256]' to 'std::complex***' in assignment

So my question is **how to correctly declare** the 3D Array `wfc` and whether maintaining this Structure approach is at all possible/useful. Would it generally be faster to access the `wfc[i][j][k]` if `wfc` was not member of a structure? (I will have to do this ~10^6 times)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd skip the `[][][]` syntax and just use a single vector. Element `[z*RES*RES+y*RES+x]` will give you the equivalent of `[z][y][x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message returns the correct declaration, `std::complex<double>(*wfc)[RES][RES];`.

```
const unsigned int RES = 256;
struct Settings {};
struct Operators {
public:
    std::complex<double>(*wfc)[RES][RES];         // edited, see 'spitconsumers' comment

    Operators(Settings& set) {        // just another structure used by Operators
        wfc = new std::complex<double>[RES][RES][RES];

        // ...Initializing wfc using Settings
        // Setting the last element
        wfc[254][254[254] = 42;

    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this was exactly what I was looking for! However I find that 'splitconsumer's solution is twice as fast when I measure the time needed to make operations of the form `T[ix][iy][iz] = std::pow(P[ix][iy][iz], 2) - n_L;` with for-loops for every `i,j,k`. Is this due to  memory allocation?

Comment: @Azure27  Sounds like the compiled code is computing each location on each access which would be quite slow as it's two multiplications and 3 adds to get an offset. That would be poor optimizer performance. Make sure to use -O3 On other problems involving cross access like array multiplication, the array of pointers approach is typically slower since processors math in cpu registers is faster than pointer accesses.

Answer (score 2):

In your error message, the compiler is telling you that `new complex [RES][RES][RES]` is returning the type `std::complex (*)[256][256]`.

`double wfc` should be `std::complex*** wfc`.

Class member types must be known, and since you are not initialising the member variable while it is being defined, the compiler cannot deduce the type of the variable, which is why `auto` doesn't work as a class member type, when you aren't immediately assigning something to it. But you are assigning the value directly to the variable in your test program, allowing the compiler to deduce the type there.

Also, the `new` operator is returning a pointer to an array of uninitialised `std::complex<double>**` pointers. You need to call `new` for all of the uninitialised pointers.

```
std::complex<double>*** wfc;

wfc = new std::complex<double>** [RES];

for(int i = 0; i < RES; i++) {
    wfc[i] = new std::complex<double>* [RES];

    for(int j = 0; j < RES; j++) {
        wfc[i][j] = new std::complex<double> [RES];

        for(int k = 0; k < RES; k++) {
            wfc[i][j][k] = /* insert default value here */;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!
Replacing `double` with `std::complex<double>***`, I now get the error
> error: cannot convert 'complex (*)[256][256]' {aka 'std::complex<double> (*)[256][256]'} to 'complex***' {aka 'std::complex<double>***'} in assignment wfc = new complex [RES][RES][RES];

Comment: the `new` statement is returning a pointer to an array of uninitialised pointers. You need to run a for look calling `new` on all the uninitialised pointers. I'll edit my answer to get your problem to be fully fixed (hopefully).

Comment: for loop*. Unfortunate typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach works fine! While it is not as short as dougs solution, I find in my performance tests that it is twice as fast with respect to element-operations like `T[ix][iy][iz] = std::pow(P[ix][iy][iz], 2) - n_L;` for every i,j,k. Is this related to how the memory is allocated?